# Monotouch add buttons in for loop

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am adding UIButtons in a for loop using this code:

```
for (int i=0; i <12; i++) {
    button = new UIButton(new RectangleF(xBase + i * 25,100 + i,25,25));
    button.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/b.png"),UIControlState.Normal);
    button.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => { 
        UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("",i.ToString(),null,"",null);
        alert.Show();
    };
    this.Add (button);
}
```

The problem is that the values I get when clicking the buttons, is of the last button added.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably becase of the nature of variables in closures in C#. Try binding the loop variable to a local variable inside the loop. You might find some relevant information [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're closing on the loop variable. And the loop variable in C# is defined outside of the loop.

You can fix your code like this

```
for (int i=0; i <12; i++) {
    button = new UIButton(new RectangleF(xBase + i * 25,100 + i,25,25));
    button.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/b.png"),UIControlState.Normal);
    button.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => { 
        var j = i;
        UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("",j.ToString(),null,"",null);
        alert.Show();
    };
this.Add (button);
```

}

Hopefully, you're doing this in a `for` loop, not a `foreach`, as the [behaviour changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) in `C# 5`, but I have no clue if that change is implemented yet in the mono 3.0.X series or not.